# How to check if my string starts with numbers from 200 to 300 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "2001234560300";
var n = str.startsWith("200    ---->   300",0);
if (n == true)
{
    alert('yes');
}
else
{
    alert('no');
}
```

//How to check if my string starts with numbers from 200 to 300 in javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a regular expression like that:

```
if (/^(2\d\d|300)/.test(str)) {
    // do something
}
```